# Python - Pass a function as argument/parameter to create a dynamic script

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I have a python script that reads messages from a Kafka topic, run some custom filtering, and produce a new message to another Kafka topic.

Currently the script accepts 2 arguments: `--source_topic` and `--target_topic`. script pseudo code:

```
for each message in source_topic:
    is_fit = check_if_message_fits_target_topic(message)
    if is_fit:
        produce(target_topic, message)
```

and i run my script like:
`python3 my_script.py --source_topic someSourceTopic --target_topic someTargetTopic`

---

My wish is to be able to make the function `check_if_message_fits_target_topic` to be dynamic so i can run the same script on-demand with different custom parameters.

I'm using `argparse` to manage the topic names arguments. What is the best way to pass a whole function as argument?

Just for the sake of the example, i have a running app that apply:

```
def check_if_message_fits_target_topic(message):
    values = message.value
    if values['event_name'] == 'some_event_name':
        return True
    return False
```

I want to build it in a generic way so i will be able to push some other custom logic, for example:

```
def check_if_message_fits_target_topic(message):
    values = message.value
    yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    if values['created_at'] > yesterday:
        return True
    return False
```

`check_if_message_fits_target_topic` should be able to do anything i pass it, as long it returns True or False.

Comment: Short of passing arbitrary Python code for your script to use `exec` or `eval` on (do *not* do this!), your script has to have *some* idea of what information you might pass in. This is basic function parameterization.

Comment: I think it will be very awkward to pass complete functions on the command line. I would look at using a config file or even a py file that you import to home your functions

Comment: chepner, @JonSG i get you guys, it feels awkward for me as well. my purpose is to find a way to avoid changing my git codebase in order to run this script with different params like JonSG suggests (config or py file). you think its somehow possible?

Comment: The usual way is a dictionary that maps names to functions. But this means you'll have to define all the possible functions in your code.

Comment: I would pass a parameter that was the name of a py file that defined a standard method or a potentially a class that based on a well know parent. This parameter would then be used to dynamically import the py file. If you want an example, let me know

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that sets a default implementation of a method that can be overridden by passing the name of a python module on the command line.  I would personally do something more nuanced with classes I think, but this might give you one path forward.

**main.py**

```
import sys
import importlib

def fn():
    print("default function implementation")

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    fn = importlib.import_module(sys.argv[1]).fn

fn()
```

**custom.py**

```py
def fn():
    print("custom function implementation")
```

Now you can do:

```
python main.py
```

and get

> default function implementation

or

```
python main.py custom
```

and get

> custom function implementation

Comment: interesting. But that means that i will necessarily have to add a lot of `custom.py` files to the git codebase in order for this solution to work?

Comment: Well, that changes the goal post immensely but the answer is easy. Import a file with lots of methods and set fn to the named method. Likely using getattr()